# MySQL Function for killing sleeping connections

Tags: mysql, sql, multithreading

I'm trying to create function that will kill all sleeping connections:

```
    CREATE DEFINER=`user`@`%` FUNCTION `kill_sleepers`() RETURNS int(11)
BEGIN
    DECLARE Id, result INT;
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE sleepers CURSOR FOR SELECT Id FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.processlist where COMMAND = 'Sleep';
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

    SET result = 0;
    OPEN sleepers;

    read_loop: LOOP
        FETCH sleepers INTO Id;
        IF done THEN
          LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;
        kill Id;
            SET result = result + 1;
    END LOOP;

    CLOSE sleepers;    
    RETURN result;
END
```

But when I run it I got 'Error Code: 1094. Unknown thread id: 0'. If I put killing into:

```
IF Id != 0 THEN
    kill Id;
    SET result = result + 1;
END IF;
```

It will kill nothing, where I'm making mistake?

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP FUNCTION KILL_SLEEPERS;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION KILL_SLEEPERS()
    RETURNS INT READS SQL DATA
    BEGIN
        DECLARE DONE INT DEFAULT FALSE;
        DECLARE VAR_ID INT;
        DECLARE ITER INT;
        DECLARE SLEEPERS CURSOR FOR SELECT ID FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCESSLIST WHERE COMMAND = 'SLEEP';
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET DONE = TRUE;
        SET ITER = 0;
        OPEN SLEEPERS;

        READ_LOOP: LOOP
            FETCH SLEEPERS INTO VAR_ID;
            IF DONE THEN
                LEAVE READ_LOOP;
            END IF;
              KILL VAR_ID;
            SET ITER = ITER + 1;
        END LOOP;
    CLOSE SLEEPERS;
    RETURN ITER;
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;

SELECT KILL_SLEEPERS();
```

Just try above code.

I had just changed variable name from `ID` to `VAR_ID`.